# The Event pressmove of CreateJS doesn't work on desktop browsers (windows touchscreen)

Tags: jquery-animate, createjs, touchscreen

I have this code  that  uses the events mousedown , pressmove and pressup ,it runs fine on Android ,IOS ,and windows (mouseEnent), but using finger touch on windows touchscreeen  I receive mousedown and pressup but the event pressmove not trigged.

```
container.addEventListener("pressup", onpressup);
container.addEventListener("pressmove", onpressmove);
container.addEventListener("mousedown", onmousedown);
```

I don't change the target after the mousedown event.
Createjs v 1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Touch interactions use different mouse events. The Touch class will convert the events for you, and should work on a multi-touch device as well.

https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Touch.html

```js
let stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasId");
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

Comment: Glad to get your reply , I have  this statements  in the code : 

stage.enableMouseOver(20);
createjs.Touch.enable(stage, false, true);
stage.preventSelection = false;

On Android, windows+mouse the code runs fine, but in the specific case of windows+finger touch, I get the Events mousedown and mouseup if I do a click on my container (I don't receive the mousedown when I put my finger on the screen, but after I lift my finger off the surface) . When I do a move : finger down + move+ finger up,  I don't get any Event.
This code runs fine.:
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handle).

Comment: I notice that the statement: createjs.Touch.enable(stage, true, false); return false even if it runs on laptop windows 10 with detachable screen. Touch runs fine for other apps on same laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation on windows touch device is correct. I had the same problem and solved it by editing createjs. I changed the Touch class in createjs with Touch class in easeljs-next. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have to change the line: window.navigator["pointerEnabled"] in the Touch class by window.PointerEvent